# Reuse Cucumber steps across features files in Cypress

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Is there a way to reuse steps in our features from "other" step files?

I.e. I have a project with login page, and topbar that I want to test after login:

[image]

Got LoginPage.feature and LoginPage.js step file, everything works fine, all tests run correctly.

[image]

I would like reuse steps “Given user open TestPage login page” and “When user login using valid credentials” from LoginPage.js in TopBarCmp.feature:

[image]

But it always ends with error:

[image]

Long time ago I used Specflow(Cucumber for .net) and it was normal to ruse steps with same singatures across all features.
What is correct way of handling that kind of situations, where we would like to use some part that was already automated?

Comment: Just set the correct configurations as here https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor#configuration

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can put them either on cypress/integration/common or in cypress/support/step_definitions and they will be available to share across features

this article explains it better https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/part-2-hands-on-test-automation-project-cypress-reis-fernandes